# Disabling folder with pages in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication, administration

i have a simple question

How to disable a folder with aspx pages in asp.net

Thw folder is "Administration" and i want to disable it that it cannot be called in browser by typing .../Administratin/edit.aspx, or that simple to redirect to a login page if we want to go to the administration part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [locations element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx) and config settings to restrict access to folders.

```
<location path="Administration">    
    <system.web>    
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Administrators" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
     </system.web>   
</location>
```

Answer (score 1):

First enable forms based authentication. This can be done for [VB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308157/EN-US) and [C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240/EN-US).

[Next you have to specify who will have access to what.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871)  This can be done in the web.config.

Apologies if these articles are a little out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Change the NTFS security permissions on the Administration Folder for

```
    <drive>:\intepub\wwwroot\...\Administration
```

and restrict access via that way.

You can also right click go to properties in IIS for the folder and remove various granular browsing permissions.

You can also edit the web.config and change permissions there.